# computing the sum $z_1^{10}+z_2^{10}+z_3^{10}+z_4^{10}+z_5^{10}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given the complex equation: $z^5+4+4i=0$, need to compute the sum:

$ z_1^{10}+z_2^{10}+z_3^{10}+z_4^{10}+z_5^{10}$

I can see that the solutions of the equation:

$\sqrt{2}cis333^0,\sqrt{2}cis261^0,\sqrt{2}cis189^0,\sqrt{2}cis117^0,1+i$

are geometric progression, but can't see how to continue.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $z_k^5 = -(4+4i)$ for $k = 1,\ldots,5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you do not even need to solve the equation.

Each root raised to the fifth power equals $-(4+4i)$. So, $z_k^{10}=(4+4i)^2= 32i$ for $k=1,2,..5$.

Hence your answer should be $160i$

Comment: didn't see that. thanks alot!